# How to generate a war file based on two subprojects

Tags: gradle, war

I have a project which is splitted into two subprojects.

```
/project
   /sub-project-a (backend with JAVA source which is compiled into JAR file)
   /sub-project-b (frontend sources which are compiled with grunt via gradle call)
   build.gradle
   settings.gradle (contains include 'sub-project-a', 'sub-project-b')
```

**My Question is** how can I create a War file with sub-projects and external lib dependencies? The following code snipped is my current build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
version '1.0.0'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':sub-project-a')
    compile project(':sub-project-b')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
task copy(type: Copy) {
    from 'sub-project-a/build', 'sub-project-b/build'
    into 'build'
}
build.dependsOn clean, copy
war {
    archiveName 'project.war'
}
```

One detail is important. The java context listener (deep inside project code) work with compiled backend as jar file from `WEB-INF/lib` folder. This means that all class files can't be easily used from `WEB-INF/classes` folder.

As you can see I played with `dependencies` and a custom `copy` task. I'm not sure what is right gradle way. How should I do this?

**SOLUTION**

Define with `war.from` methode, where you get your static sources.

> [gradle docu](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html)
>   from(sourcePaths) -
>   Specifies source files or directories for a copy. The given paths are
>   evaluated as per Project.files().

My changed build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'
version '1.0.0'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {        
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}    
war {
    archiveName 'project.war'
    from 'sub-project-a/build/dist', 'sub-project-b/build/dist'
}
```

Comment: As you already have your own solution, you should post it as an answer to this question so that it isn't listed as unanswered anymore.

Comment: Please post as an answer.

Comment: Sry, I tried but there is a char limit at comments.

Comment: Comment != answer. The answer form is below, right under "Your Answer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLUTION (for cleanly closing this question) shamefully taken from the question's originator ;-)

Define subproject dependencies with the "war.from" method, where you get your static sources.

> [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html) excerpt: from(sourcePaths) - Specifies source files or directories
>   for a copy. The given paths are evaluated as per Project.files().

Ronny's changed build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'
version '1.0.0'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {        
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}    
war {
    archiveName 'project.war'
    from 'sub-project-a/build/dist', 'sub-project-b/build/dist'
}
```

Comment: it seems there is not `dist` folder anymore 5 years later! I don't even see a directory after running the war command that has web-inf/libs etc folders. Would you know what's the relevant answer now?

Comment: @Sap did you find the answer to your question?